# Want to get value from the below code snippet through Web Driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver

```
<script> jQuery(function()
{jQuery("#chart").kendoChart({"chartArea":{"background":"#f7f7f7"}
"title":{"position":"top"}
"legend":{"visible":false}
"series":[{"name":"Consumption"
"color":"#0000FF"
"type":"column"
"data":["1320649","1301971","1312053","0","0","0","0"]}]
"seriesDefaults":{"column":{"stack":true}}
"categoryAxis":[{"labels":{"rotation":360
"visible":true}
"majorGridLines":{"visible":false}
"line":{"visible":false}
"title":{"text":"Date"}
"categories":["08/10 \n Mo"
"08/11 \n Tu"
"08/12 \n We"
"08/13 \n Th"
"08/14 \n Fr"
"08/15 \n Sa"
"08/16 \n Su"]}]
"valueAxis":[{"labels":{"format":"n0"}
"line":{"visible":false}
"title":{"text":"G"}}]
"tooltip":{"template":"#=kendo.toString(parseFloat(value)
 \u0027n0\u0027)#"
"visible":true}});});
```

This data is generating SVG charts.

This code is inside HTML. Also the values above are "," separated like title,legend,series etc.

I want the data from the data string. It has daily consumption values. I want each of them so that I can apply assert to check the success.

How can I get the number in some variable in my java code (webdriver)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first took the the above data in a string.
then i used the regex to extract the

```
 "data":["1320649","1301971","1312053","0","0","0","0"]}]
```

part. After this i again used the regex to extract the numbers only and so on and so forth. It was tedious but it worked good.

I took regex according so that on any day if the string changes some how my code should be able to handle it.

**Here is my code :**

```
 WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='statictics-chart-enforce-reload-wrapper']/script[1]"));
        String str = ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        String mydata = str;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("data\":\\[(.*?)]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find())
        {

            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            mydata=matcher.group(1);
        }

        String arr[] = mydata.split(",");
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            day[i]=Integer.parseInt(arr[i].replace("\"",""));
            System.out.println(day[i]);
        }
```

This way I am able to get the values.

Do let me know if any one has a more simpler version.

Thanks in Advance